# Check if certain word already has span as a wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have multiple div elements and they contain beside some text an email addresses written like this +example@email.com. Now I'm trying to add span as a wrapper around each email address. I found solution to replace  each word that starts with + with some span element and text. Is there a way I can check if +example@email.com already has a span? I don't want to wrap it multiple times. I'm using coffeescript

```
wrapAllThreadEmails = ->
  $('.comment-body-area').each (comment) ->
    text = $(this).html().replace(/\s\+(.*?)(\s|$)/g, '<span> +$1</span>$2')
    $(this).html(text)
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can first check if the returned HTML matches for a `<span>`:

```coffee
wrapAllThreadEmails = ->
  $('.comment-body-area').each (comment) ->
    if not $(this).html().match(/<span>/) # Check for matching <span> here
      text = $(this).html().replace(/\s\+(.*?)(\s|$)/g, '<span> +$1</span>$2')
      $(this).html(text)
```

You can also drop the `return` from your function, [CoffeeScript will always return the final value](https://coffeescript.org/#expressions) of an expression.